# How to set filter for GridView in EditValue changed ? Winforms Devexpress

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, gridview

I need to filter the gridview when user select some item from dropdown. So I write this query code in edit value change event but my query is error

```
SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, 
(Select CustomerId from Customer Where Customer.CustomerId=NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerId, 
(Select CustomerName from Customer where Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerName, 
DueDate, Tax, GrandTotal, CompanyId
FROM NewInvoice_1
Where InvoiceDate < 06-04-2014; // error in where condition
```

I have 6 conditions here to filter this invoice date

1) InvoiceDate before 01-04-2014

2) InvoiceDate startfrom 01-03-2014 endon 31-0302014

3) InvoiceDate thisweek that is last 7 days from now

4) InvoiceDate lastweek that is now(Today) - 14 days to +7 days

5) InvoiceDate ThisMonth that is last 30 days from now

6) InvoiceDate LastMonth that is now(today) - 60 days to +30 days

Help me to how to form query for this

Comment: Why you want to use devexpress filter option rather than you can use `DataView` filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue in how you pass the date.

```
 SELECT InvoiceId, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, 
 (Select CustomerId from Customer Where Customer.CustomerId=NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerId, 
 (Select CustomerName from Customer where Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerName, 
 DueDate, Tax, GrandTotal, CompanyId
 FROM NewInvoice_1
 Where InvoiceDate < '06-04-2014';
```

This might work or pass the date as CDate('06-04-2014')